# keep getting fatal error: moveit/utils/logger.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: ikfast, logger, moveit2

I keep getting this error when trying to build ikfast plugin for moveit2, any ideas why?

```
    ammar@ammarpc:~/WSG_Panzer_ROS/ros2_ws$ colcon build --packages-select panzerbot_ikfast_pkg 
[1.096s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.package_augmentation:Exception in package augmentation extension 'python': 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/package_augmentation/__init__.py", line 97, in augment_packages
    retval = extension.augment_packages(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_installed_package_information/package_augmentation/python.py", line 44, in augment_packages
    dist = next(iter(dists))
StopIteration

Starting >>> panzerbot_ikfast_pkg
--- stderr: panzerbot_ikfast_pkg                               
/home/ammar/WSG_Panzer_ROS/ros2_ws/src/panzerbot_ikfast_pkg/src/panzerbot_arm_group_ikfast_moveit_plugin.cpp:51:10: fatal error: moveit/utils/logger.hpp: No such file or directory
   51 | #include <moveit/utils/logger.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/panzerbot_arm_group_moveit_ikfast_plugin.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/panzerbot_arm_group_moveit_ikfast_plugin.dir/src/panzerbot_arm_group_ikfast_moveit_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:165: CMakeFiles/panzerbot_arm_group_moveit_ikfast_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< panzerbot_ikfast_pkg [11.7s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [12.7s]
  1 package failed: panzerbot_ikfast_pkg
  1 package had stderr output: panzerbot_ikfast_pkg
ammar@ammarpc:~/WSG_Panzer_ROS/ros2_ws$
```

Comment: Have you checked that the file `moveit/utils/logger.hpp` exists? Are your paths set correctly?

Comment: X-posted to reddit: [fatal error: moveit/utils/logger.hpp: No such file or directory](https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/1bg6ezk/fatal_error_moveitutilsloggerhpp_no_such_file_or/). Please read [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251469/4424636) and [Is it OK to cross-post a question between non-Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266053/4424636)

Comment: It doesn't exist in the path mentioned,  but moveit ikfast generated code has this include, even the KDL built in kinematics has this include line.